# Why Kernel does not upgrade despite enable HWE on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 (64bit) on Raspberry Pi 4 almost a years ago.
Then I have installed a update to 20.04.2 and enable HWE.
But it does not upgrade kernel to 5.8.
I have no idea why it does not so Current version of kernel is `5.4.0-1034-raspi`

How I can upgrade kernel to 5.8?

Comment: According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-image-raspi-hwe-18.04 both Bionic (18.04) and Focal (20.04) for the Raspberry Pi are using the same HWE kernel version of 5.4.0-1034.  Unfortunately, there is no 5.8 for Raspberry Pi 20.04 installation yet.

Comment: @Terrance Why it does not release yet?

Comment: There could be bugs, etc that they are working out in that kernel version before they push it.  It is there, but so far only in the groovy/proposed that I can see:  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/5.8.0-1015.18